# Import Server Certificates into Keystore using asp.net to validate Request is coming from trusted server

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, ssl, ssl-certificate

Hi Can anyone give me a solution how to import server certificate into a keystore to validate the request is coming from valid client.

I have gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19840563/using-x509certificate-with-file-and-key-in-c-sharp) article but having few questions.

1) How will my server validate the client certificate ?

2) Will this(X509Certificate) .net class validate Genie(Tivoli) certificate ?

3) Do i need to have certificate configured on my server ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to know how IIS verifies client certificates, you might read carefully this KB 907274 for your 1) and 3)

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/907274

For an ASP.NET site, it has no chance to verify the certificate as the verification is done at IIS level (http.sys generally). Thus, `X509Certificate` class is less relevant, unless you want to further check the verified client certificate for more info. This is for 2).

Comment: How can i import server certificate into keystore ?